# First Ajax Request in Chrome Fails, succeeds in Firefox and IE

Tags: asp.net, angular, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I have an Angular2 application talking to an ASP.NET WebAPI endpoint, that uses Windows Auth for authentication, that is failing to respond on first request in Chrome.

The first visit the application makes a request to an endpoint that requires authentication. In Chrome the OPTIONS request succeeds, in the application OPTIONS request have been configured to always succeed, but when the GET request is made it fails. In Dev Tools under request headers it shows the provisional headers warning message for that request. When you refresh the browser the endpoint responds successfully.

In IE11 and Firefox it is working as expected, the OPTIONS and GET request succeed.

Not sure if this is an Angular2, ASP.NET WebAPI, or IIS Configuration issue.

*Update*
This looks like it's related to how Chrome has implemented HTTP/2. Firefox will try the request again using HTTP/1.1 if the HTTP/2 request fails.

*Update 2*

Chrome stores the first request protocol and uses that protocol for future request. My OPTIONS request is always responding to HTTP/2 requests with 200 success. Which chrome stores as yes this server supports HTTP/2 request, continue to use it going forward. When the API GET request goes with NTLM authentication it fails because HTTP/2 does not support NTLM authentication. Chrome stores that failure and the next time it will try HTTP/1.1 which succeeds. I have filed a bug report with Chromium because I think it should treat all NTLM authentication requests as HTTP/1.1 because NTLM is not supported by HTTP/2.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=713851